# How to create a repeated dataframe over time and map it to a list of time?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I have created the below dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = pd.date_range(start="2019-12-01", end="2019-12-20", freq='D')
```

```
Output:
    date
0   2019-12-01
1   2019-12-02
2   2019-12-03
3   2019-12-04
4   2019-12-05
5   2019-12-06
6   2019-12-07
7   2019-12-08
8   2019-12-09
9   2019-12-10
10  2019-12-11
11  2019-12-12
12  2019-12-13
13  2019-12-14
14  2019-12-15
15  2019-12-16
16  2019-12-17
17  2019-12-18
18  2019-12-19
19  2019-12-20
```

And I have following two lines

```
Line Start        End         Amount
A    2019-12-01  2019-12-08   100
B    2019-12-06  2019-12-15   200
```

I want to have the following result:

```
Output:
    date         amount   line
0   2019-12-01   100       A
1   2019-12-02   100       A
2   2019-12-03   100       A
3   2019-12-04   100       A
4   2019-12-05   100       A
5   2019-12-06   300       A,B
6   2019-12-07   300       A,B
7   2019-12-08   300       A,B
8   2019-12-09   200       B
9   2019-12-10   200       B 
10  2019-12-11   200       B
11  2019-12-12   200       B
12  2019-12-13   200       B
13  2019-12-14   200       B
14  2019-12-15   200       B
15  2019-12-16   0
16  2019-12-17   0
17  2019-12-18   0
18  2019-12-19   0
19  2019-12-20   0
```

What can I do to achieve this? I have tried to use "map" function but I cant get the result.

Sorry guys, if the two lines have a index, how can i also add that column in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.assume your second list as a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = pd.date_range(start="2019-12-01", end="2019-12-20", freq='D')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Start":["2019-12-01","2019-12-06"],"End":["2019-12-08","2019-12-15"],"Amount":[100,200]})
df2["Start"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Start"])
df2["End"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["End"])

def f(x):

    df_ = df2[(df2.Start<= x) & (df2.End>=x)]["Amount"]
    v = df_.values
    i = df_.index.values      
    return v,i

s=df.date.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({"amount":sum(f(x)[0]),"line":','.join(map(str, f(x)[1]))}))
df= pd.concat([df,s],axis=1)
```

in here line is index of the second data frame (df2).If you need line starting from 1, you can change this line by adding 1 to index values. `i = df_.index.values+1`
output

```
          date  amount line
0  2019-12-01     100    0
1  2019-12-02     100    0
2  2019-12-03     100    0
3  2019-12-04     100    0
4  2019-12-05     100    0
5  2019-12-06     300  0,1
6  2019-12-07     300  0,1
7  2019-12-08     300  0,1
8  2019-12-09     200    1
9  2019-12-10     200    1
10 2019-12-11     200    1
11 2019-12-12     200    1
12 2019-12-13     200    1
13 2019-12-14     200    1
14 2019-12-15     200    1
15 2019-12-16       0     
16 2019-12-17       0     
17 2019-12-18       0     
18 2019-12-19       0     
19 2019-12-20       0
```

Comment: Sorry, if the two lines have a index, how can i also add that column in the result?

Comment: what do you mean by ` two lines have a index`?

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please take a look?

Comment: great,happy coding

Comment: Sorry. how if the line index is changed to string? like A and B. in this case, index.values cannot perform such result

Comment: @KevinKwong no issue.because it takes the index of the df2 dataframe.

Comment: but how if i want to show A/B instead of 0/1 ? i have revised the expected output. Please take a look

Comment: if your df2 indexes are A,B, it will return to your final dataframe as it is.`df_.index.values` means whatever index in your dataframe.change the df2 indexes to A,B and run and check the output.

Comment: Or in this way.. if A & B are not index but they are a one of the column in df2. How to make it works? Shall I change this column as the index for df2?

Comment: easiest way it make A,B to index of df2. if it is a new column ,lets say column name is "Line" change these lines `df_ = df2[(df2.Start<= x) & (df2.End>=x)][["Amount","Line"]]
    v = df_.Amount.values
    i = df_.Line.values`

Comment: Cool. That's exactly what I want. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I believe this gives the results you want with the data structured the way it is:

```
df['date'] = pd.date_range(start="2019-12-01", end="2019-12-20", freq='D')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Start":["2019-12-01","2019-12-06"],"End":["2019-12-08","2019-12-15"],"Amount":[100,200]})

df2.End = df2.End.apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x))
df2.Start = df2.Start.apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x)) 

df['AM1']  = df.apply(lambda x: df2.Amount[0] if (x.date >= df2.Start[0] and x.date <= df2.End[0]) else 0 , axis = 1)
df['AM2']  = df.apply(lambda x: df2.Amount[1] if (x.date >= df2.Start[1] and x.date <= df2.End[1]) else 0 , axis = 1)
df['Amount'] = df.iloc[:, 1:3].sum(axis=1)
df['line'] = df.groupby(['date']).apply(lambda x: '0' if x.AM1[0] > 0 and x.AM2[0] == 0 else '1' if x.AM2[0] > 0 and x.AM1[0] == 0 else '' if x.AM1[0] == 0 and x.AM2[0] == 0 else '0, 1').to_list() 
df.drop(columns=['AM1', 'AM2'], inplace=True)
```

output:

```
         date  Amount  line
0  2019-12-01     100     0
1  2019-12-02     100     0
2  2019-12-03     100     0
3  2019-12-04     100     0
4  2019-12-05     100     0
5  2019-12-06     300  0, 1
6  2019-12-07     300  0, 1
7  2019-12-08     300  0, 1
8  2019-12-09     200     1
9  2019-12-10     200     1
10 2019-12-11     200     1
11 2019-12-12     200     1
12 2019-12-13     200     1
13 2019-12-14     200     1
14 2019-12-15     200     1
15 2019-12-16       0      
16 2019-12-17       0      
17 2019-12-18       0      
18 2019-12-19       0      
19 2019-12-20       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution with cross merge/join:

```
(pd.merge(*[d.assign(dummy=1) for d in [df, df1]], 
          on='dummy')
   .query('Start <= date <= End')
   .groupby('date')['Amount'].sum()
   .reindex(df['date'], fill_value=0)
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
         date  Amount
0  2019-12-01     100
1  2019-12-02     100
2  2019-12-03     100
3  2019-12-04     100
4  2019-12-05     100
5  2019-12-06     300
6  2019-12-07     300
7  2019-12-08     300
8  2019-12-09     200
9  2019-12-10     200
10 2019-12-11     200
11 2019-12-12     200
12 2019-12-13     200
13 2019-12-14     200
14 2019-12-15     200
15 2019-12-16       0
16 2019-12-17       0
17 2019-12-18       0
18 2019-12-19       0
19 2019-12-20       0
```

Comment: how if i have a 100 lines? do i have to create a loop to generate 100 df ?

Comment: No, you don't need to loop. the line `for d in [df,df1]` only loops over the two dataframes.

Comment: Sorry i don't quite understand on the (pd.merge(*[d.assign(dummy=1) for d in [df, df1]], on='dummy'), can you please explain a little bit?

Comment: that's equivalent to `pd.merge(df.assign(dummy=1), df1.assign(dummy=1), on='dummy')`. I was just showing off :D. Also, `df.assign(dummy=1)` is almost equivalent to `df['dummy']=1` without really touching `df`.